# Auto focus next input inside a div

Tags: jquery, css

```
<td><div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3"/></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3"/></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3"/></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3"/></div></td>
```

the structure of my design goes as the above, now my problem is i can't auto focus the next input. maybe there is a conflict in div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').keyup(function(){
    if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr("maxlength")) {
      $(this).next().focus();
    }
  });
});
```

and my code goes like this, when i remove the div between inputs it runs well. but my inputs does not align anymore. Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `input` elements are not siblings, so `next()` will not work.

You instead need to get the parent div of the current input, go to the next div, then find the input within that:

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr("maxlength")) {
    $(this).closest('div').next().find('input').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3" /></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

That's because input elements are not siblings, their parent divs are.

you need to traverse to parent div, then next sibling div and then find input in it:

```
$(this).closest('.col-xs-3').next().find('input').focus();
```

Do make sure you add a check to see if next div exist. before finding the input element it. otherwise this will be throwing error in case of last div. something like this:

```
var $nextCloX3 = $(this).closest('.col-xs-3').next();
if($nextCloX3.length > 0)
   $nextCloX3.find('input').focus();
```

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr("maxlength")) {
    var $nextCloX3 = $(this).closest('.col-xs-3').next();
    if($nextCloX3.length > 0)
     $nextCloX3.find('input').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3" /></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The check is redundant and no error will be thrown. jQuery is smart enough to know when a collection is empty when calling a method on it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that in that context, `this` is the `input` but there is no `next` within that `div`

so change it to this:

```
// get this, go the parent div, go to next div, find the input, focus
$(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwgdLuuy/1/

Answer (score 0):

next() is not referenced to the next input, so you could do something like this. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length==$(this).attr("maxlength")){
        $(this).parent('div').next().find('input').focus();
    }
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3"/></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3"/></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3"/></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"><input type="text" maxlength="3"/></div></td>
```